# Bitcoin-cli using getblock to retrieve historical data

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I have recently set up a bitcoin node using bitcoind and want to perform some historical queries on the blockchain using getblock with verbosity set to 2.

I am using the default bitcoin.conf file but was wondering what's the best configuration to use to be able to query the blockchain historically?

Do I need to download the full blockchain using reindex or can I run a pruned node and still use getblock to get information on the genises block?

I know in order to use getRawTransaction you need to set txindex=1, but can I not get the same information from getblock (verbosity 2) in the tx array?